Why do negative irrationals not work for $x^x$?
I was watching a yt video on the domain of $x^x$ and for the case of negative $x$ it specifically mentioned that "irrational numbers will not work". Why?
Some negative rational numbers - those of the form $\frac{n}{1-2k}$ for natural $n$ and $k$ with $\gcd(n, 2k-1) = 1$ - work, e.g. ${(-\frac{1}{3})}^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ is fine. But then - can't we just build an irrational number as a limit of the sequence of rational numbers, each of which is of the aforementioned form $\frac{n}{1-2k}$ and that sequence converges to an irrational number $\alpha$, therefore making it possible to define that ${\alpha}^{\alpha}$? Or is this not enough?
I've seen an argument against it that goes like this: "For irrational $x$ we define (?) $x^x$ as $e^{x\ln(x)}$ and that will not work for $x<0$" - but I disagree with it since the same "definition" would fail on the rational numbers for which we've just seen above it all works out well.
TL;DR: Is it really the case that negative irrational $x$ cannot be part of the domain of $x^x$ and if so, why exactly?

It's not even clear how you would define a real value to $(-\sqrt2)^{-\sqrt2}.$ What would be your proposed value? If you allow complex values, there are infinitely many possible complex values for this expression, but none of them are real. So, for real functions, we tend t9 define $a^x$ only for $a>0.3

What makes you think every such sequence would converge to the same value?

@ThomasAndrews I don't know? My point wasn't in that every negative irrational number could work, just that we can probably build some that will.

It fails to work for a negative rational number as well, try $\frac{-2}{7}$

$x^x$ is defined in the set of reals only for certain negative values of $x$. If you sketch its graph, between any $2$ real values of $x$, there will be infinitely many points at which this will be defined(like the type of rational values you mentioned), but infinitely many more values at which it will not be defined. So, its graph cannot be drawn for negative values of $x$, hence the argument $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$ is plausible.

A tricky thing here is that there are a number of different definitions for $x^y$: one when $x$ is a positive real number, and one when $y$ is an integer. In the complex numbers, there's also $x^y = \exp(y \ln(x))$ where $\ln$ is the logarithm's principal branch, but that's not continuous. So to describe the domain of $x^x$, the first question should be, "what exactly do you mean by $x^x$?"

You seem to be under the impression that $x^\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is irrational, is defined as a limit $x^{\alpha_n}$, where $\alpha_n$ is a rational sequence tending to $\alpha$, and presumably rational exponentiation is defined as usual, using $p$th powers and $q$th roots. This is not how it is typically defined.
Usually, the function $\exp(x) = e^x$ is defined first. It can be defined as a Taylor series. It can be defined as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + x/n)^n$ (where the exponentiation there is repeated multiplication). It can be defined as the provably unique solution to the IVP $y' = y$, where $y(0) = 1$. Or, it could be defined as the inverse of $\ln x$, where $\ln x := \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$. There are several ways of doing this, and $\ln$ is defined as its inverse (or it's defined first, in the latter method).
Then, we define $x^\alpha := \exp(\alpha \ln x)$. Here, of course, we get the baked-in requirement that $x > 0$; we cannot evaluate $\ln x$ for $x < 0$.
Your definition will work, in the sense that you will get back to the same values of $x^\alpha$... eventually. Your definition is cumbersome and somewhat difficult to work with. How do you know, for example, that changing the rational approximating sequence won't change the limit $x^{\alpha_n}$? How do you know that it will converge at all? These things can be proven, but it's usually preferred, if possible, to have a definition that is easy to use to prove things, and doesn't require so much work to show that it's well-defined.
But, we don't seem to have any better way on hand to define $x^x$, where $x < 0$. Perhaps, cumbersome as it may be, we could define $\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}$, and others, by considering limits of rational powers with odd denominators? Perhaps it'll lead to something useful?
No, it doesn't really. It falls prey to the well-definedness trap. Choosing a different rational sequence $x_n \to x < 0$ will affect the convergence of $x_n^{x_n}$, either causing it to tend to $(-x)^x$, or $-(-x)^x$, or more likely, oscillating between both and causing the sequence not to converge.
To see how this would work, consider the repeating decimal:
$$0.\overline{d_1d_2\ldots d_n}.$$
Standard manipulations reveal that this decimal can be written as the fraction
$$\frac{d_1d_2\ldots d_n}{10^n - 1},$$
where $d_1d_2 \ldots d_n$ represents an $n$-digit number (as opposed to multiplication).
Note that the denominator here is always odd, so such rational numbers are always appropriate for our purposes. We can approximate any negative real number
$$x = -0.d_1d_2d_3d_4\ldots$$
by
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= -0.\overline{d_1} = -\frac{d_1}{9} \\
x_2 &= -0.\overline{d_1d_2} = -\frac{d_1d_2}{99} \\
x_3 &= -0.\overline{d_1d_2d_3} = -\frac{d_1d_2d_3}{999} \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
Now, if $d_n$ is even, then $x_n$ will be a fraction with an even numerator, and so due to even powers eliminating the sign, $x_n^{x_n}$ will be positive, i.e. $x_n^{x_n} = (-x_n)^{x_n}$. If, on the other hand, $d_n$ is odd, then we will get $x_n^{x_n} = -(-x_n)^{x_n}$. In the limit, the former case tends to $(-x)^x$, and the latter case tends to $-(-x)^x$. So, if the decimal expansion fails to run out of odd or even digits eventually, then $x_n^{x_n}$ will not converge.
Even if the digits were all eventually even or eventually odd, we could still just tweak every other digit, adding $1$ or possibly subtracting $1$ if the digit were $9$. We could force the final digit to be the parity of our choosing, and it would not affect convergence of the rational sequence, but it would affect the properties of convergence.
So, all in all, this definition is not well-defined.

Thanks, it's insightful. But I also got this logic from your post: "there's an example of an irrational number where the definition you propose doesn't work => it doesn't work" - and it's fair, but my point was to say that there could be some irrational numbers that will work with this definition. However, if we indeed canonically define $x^x$ as $exp(xln(x))$ then my point is moot as I'm not trying to argue about definitions.

The example was actually pretty general; any number in $[0, 1]$ can be written in the form $0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots$, and for numbers outside this range, we can write it as the sum of an integer and such a number. This same problem will happen when defining $x^x$ for any negative, non-integer $x$ (including irrationals!). And yes, canonically, that is the definition of $x^x$, but that doesn't mean that other ideas aren't interesting.

So, you mean that the logic goes like this: Any irrational number can be written in this form -> We've shown that in this form there are issues -> These issues emerge for any irrational number -> We can't really use it for any irrational number? Also, if I got it right, the core issue is that finding one converging sequence isn't enough, we need to show that any converging sequence will yield the same result - is that correct?

Any negative irrational number, and yes, otherwise, that's my logic. And yes to the question about sequences, otherwise $x^x$ doesn't depend only $x$, but there's a hidden dependency on how you've approximated $x$. Also, in my answer (c.f. my second-last paragraph) I talk about how you can tweak the construction to get convergence to either answer, or divergence, by modifying the final digit in each approximation. So, in other words, different sequences produce different results, and indeed most will just fail to converge anyway.

Yes, the condition that any such sequence must converge to the same value seems reasonable to me. I think that clarifies this issue, thank you.

My pleasure. :)

$$x^x=e^{x\ln x}$$ and $\ln x$ is defined for $x>0$. For any $a>0$,
$$-a\ln(-a)=-a\ln a- aiπ-2akπi,k\in\mathbb{Z} $$
Which gives multiple values for the same $a$. Even if we take $k=0$, then
$$e^{-a\ln(-a)}=e^{-a\ln a}e^{-aiπ}=a^{-a}({\cos(aπ)-i\sin(aπ)})$$
Which returns real values only when $\sin(aπ)=0$ or $a\in\mathbb{Z}$
So we might say that only negative integers are included in the domain, rather than rationals
Edit
After seeing the video, he is using $(x)^\frac pq=(x)^\frac{mp}{mq}$ and $(x)^\frac pq=(x^p)^\frac 1q$, both of which are true only for positive numbers. Else, $x^2+1=0$ would have solutions as $±1$ because $±(-1)^\frac 12=±(-1)^\frac 24=±(-1^2)^\frac 14=±(1)^\frac 14=±1$ in place of $±i$

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}\subset \mathbb{Q}$ be the set of rationals with an odd denominator. Define exponentiation with $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ exponents by $x^{y/z}=t$ where $t$ is the unique real solution to the odd degree polynomial $g(t):=t^z-x^y=0$.
Using this, $x\mapsto x^x$ defines a map $f:\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x):=x^x$. Now you are asking if we can add points to the domain by defining $f(x)$ for $x\not \in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ by a limit of values $f(y_i)$ for $(y_i)$ a sequence of points in $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ tending to $x$. This does not work because the map is not continuous on the domain $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$. This is illustrated by Yves Daoust's example: $x^x$ may be far from $y^y$ no matter how close $x$ and $y$ are.
